# Create arc from MultiPoints Topojson in d3.js

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, geojson, topojson

I'm new to d3 and have following problem: I want to display positions and trails of all kind of ships. The data is in topojson format: Every ship has an array of positions in form of  lat/lon. I want to connect these positions with an arc.

Thats my code displaying the ships at their last position, which works fine (see pic). To get the trails I have a nested for loop which is probably not the best option, although I am able to print out the correct lat/lon. I just have no clue how to proceed from there and draw an arc connecting theses positions.

Any help is appreciated!

```
d3.json("ships/container-topo.json", function(error, collection) {

//latest position as point (works)
ships.append("path")
     .datum(topojson.feature(collection, collection.objects.collection))
     .attr("class", "points")
     .style("fill", "black")
     .style( "opacity", ".9" )
     .attr("d", path)

    features = collection.objects.collection.geometries

    for (var k = 0; k < features.length; k++){
        for (var i = 0; i < features[i].coordinates.length0; i++){
            cx = features[k].coordinates[i][0];
                    cy = features[k].coordinates[i][1];
                    var p_coords = projection( [cx, cy] );
                    console.log( cx );
                            //WHAT TO DO HERE?

                }
    }
```

});

The data is in following format

```
{
"type": "Topology",
"objects": {
    "collection": {
        "type": "GeometryCollection",
        "geometries": [{
            "type": "MultiPoint",
            "coordinates": [

            ]
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553811/coordinate-trigonometry-calculate-midpoint-in-arc-for-flightpath) may help.