# in d3.geo how can I vary a LineString segment's path

Tags: d3.js, geo

I am drawing paths of some shipment routes on a map, using naturalearth's geojson for map and mercator as the projection. When two routes overlap, how do I map them slightly apart?

I happen to have several shipments that have some overlap in their paths. E.g., `Chicago->Memphis->Miami` and `Chicago->Memphis->Atlanta`. I am drawing each segment (such as `Chicago->Memphis`) separately as I want to color code the LineString.

Because of the overlapping route segments, one overwrites the other and the resulting display is not very communicative. What I would like to have instead is a slight variation in the path drawn (like one sees in airline magazines where they show multiple flights between same destination points). Is this possible given that I have picked a specific projection? How can I code it differently? Fidelity to actual geographic route is not all that important since rails, trucks, or planes anyway seldom follow the shortest path.

I generate line segments as:

```
results.segments = _.reduce(results.points, function (acc, v, i, raw) {
    if (i) {
        acc.push({
            feature: {
                type: "LineString",
                coordinates: [
                    [raw[i - 1].LONGITUDE, raw[i - 1].LATITUDE],
                    [raw[i].LONGITUDE, raw[i].LATITUDE]
                ]
            },
            segment_delayed: raw[i].arrived_late
        })
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```

and then show as:

```
route.selectAll("path")
    .data(results.segments)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", function (d) {
        return path(d.feature);
    })
    .attr("stroke", function(d) {
        return d.segment_delayed ? "red" : "black";
    })
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think it's going to be easy to get it looking exactly as you want, but you could (a) add a slight translation to the path as a whole to shift it a pixel up or down; or (b) modify your data before calculating the projection, so that the lat & lon of duplicated points is shifted slightly for each.

Comment: Thanks Amelia. I tried that but visually still not what I wanted. Maybe something else like an arc or a bezier and abandon the geo/path except for the xy coordinates. I also need spacing to add some annotations.

Comment: Drawing curves is probably the way to go, since you're only concerned with start and end points and not specific street routes.  [This Q&A is probably a good start](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21553811/3128209).  You'll need to keep track of how many different routes you have along a given segment, and increase the sweep of the curve accordingly.